# Estimation of quantile regression by hand

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, quantiles, excel, quantile-regression

Let us suppose we have following data

```
x   y
1   5
2   4
3   5
4   4
5   7
```

I would like to   do  Quantile regression in excel,  I have found following information about given method

[image]

based on  this information let choose $q=75$ or  75% quantile, in excel I have done following  structure, first  create dummy variable  based on indicator  function and also choose  arbitrary values of alpha and beta 
$$\alpha=0.1 $$
$$\beta=0.2 $$
dummy variable has been  filled using following method

[image]

initially all values  are zero,  now I have calculated  one column  for sum

[image]

and finally I have calculated  sum of all  those values, and  then using solver I have estimated coefficients which  minimizes sum, I have got following values and result

[image]

please tell me  if I am wrong, and also  statistically  could you explain me  please what does this mean? What does those coefficient  describe in terms of  quantile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(A little bit more a long comment than an answer, but I'm missing the repetition to comment)

First, your calculation of the loss appears to be correct (this is `R` code):

```
y <- c(5, 4, 5, 4, 7)
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
a <- 0.217092
b <- 1.594303
tau <- 0.75
f <- function(par, y, x, tau) {
    sum((tau - (y  <= par[1] + par[2]*x)) * (y - (par[1] + par[2]*x)))  
}
f(par=c(a, b), y=y, x=x, tau=tau)
[1] 3.782908
```

Second, there seems to be a problem with the Excel solver. Using `R`'s optimizer, we find:

```
optim(c(0.1, 0.2), f, y=y, x=x, tau=tau)
$par
[1] 4.4999998 0.4999998

$value
[1] 1.250001

$counts
function gradient 
 143       NA
```

so the loss is lower using `optim` than using Excel's solver.

Third, note that your approach of estimating quantile regression is inferior to solving the corresponding linear program. Anyway, a comparison with Roger Koenker's `quantreg`package yields:

```
library(quantreg)
rq(y ~ x, tau=tau)
Call:
rq(formula = y ~ x, tau = tau)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           x 
        4.5         0.5 

Degrees of freedom: 5 total; 3 residual
```

which is very close to the solution of `R`'s `optim` solver.

About your other question: could you elaborate what exactly you want to understand?

Comment: thanks for reply,  @BayerSe so my approach for solving Qantile regression is correct right?  in shortly what we  estimated   and  what is  the meaning of  those coefficients?

Comment: @datodatuashvili Yes, your general approach is sound (but there is some problem with Excels' solver). You here estimate the parameters of a linear quantile regression model where you model the 75% quantile of the conditional distribution of your dependent variable. Your question about the meaning of the coefficients is unclear - meaning in what sense?

Comment: their role, ok  clear thanks in advance,  so does it means that excel solver is unstable while we are   trying to minimize L1 norms? or sum of absolute deviations?

Comment: Did you play around with the solver options? According to https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-and-solve-a-problem-by-using-Solver-5d1a388f-079d-43ac-a7eb-f63e45925040  there should be three different solvers. Maybe one of them works better. But generally, I would avoid doing stuff like that in Excel ...

Comment: i am using matlab and i would like ti implement matlab code for this

Comment: I see. Check out Koenker's website, he has some basic Matlab code there: http://www.econ.uiuc.edu/~roger/research/rq/rq.html. But generally, R or Python are better supported by the community than Matlab for quantile regression.

Comment: thanks sir, at least for education  point of view, i will  write matlab code(also i am frequently using matlab programming language) thanks for your attention

Comment: matlab solution is equivalent to  R  solution >> x = fminsearch(f,a_b,options)

x =

    4.5000    0.5000

Answer (score 3):

solving solution using matlab,  on the base of @BayerSe (thanks my friend,i always respect humans who share their knowledge to others), i have solved this problem in matlab

1. define objective function

   f=@(a) sum((q-(y<=a(1)+a(2)*x)).*(y-a(1)-a(2)*x))

make initial  guess of   $\alpha$ and $\beta$  and $q$

```
a_b = [0.1,0.2];
```

$q=0.75$

and finally  solve

```
options = optimset('PlotFcns',@optimplotfval);
x = fminsearch(f,a_b,options)

x =

    4.5000    0.5000
```

[image]